# Weird matplotlib output when plotting 2 scatters on the same axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can't figure out why draw behaves weird, and the other 2 functions work fine. Everything seems to work when X_test, y_test are manually typed data, yet for my particular data the draw fuction fails, even though they are the right shape.
I posted a link to an image with the plot results below.
This is on Python 3.5 via a Jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw(X_test, y_test):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(X_test, y_test, c='g', marker='o')  
    ax.scatter(X_test, y_test+5, c='r', marker = '^')
    plt.show()

def drawTest1(X_test, y_test):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(X_test, y_test, c='g', marker='o')  
    plt.show()

def drawTest2(X_test, y_test):
     fig = plt.figure()
     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
     ax.scatter(X_test, y_test+5, c='r', marker = '^')
     plt.show()

print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
drawTest1(X_test, y_test)
drawTest2(X_test, y_test)
draw(X_test, y_test)
```

[the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDx28.png)

edit: There are no strings, both X_test and y_test are numbers

Comment: Do not use strings when you want numbers on the axes.

Comment: Try again sharing the y axis, `ax.scatter(..., sharey=True)`

Comment: @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest X_test is a df containing int64, and y_test a df containing float64, neither is a string. If it was, how did y_test+5 work?

Comment: @fernandezcuesta That returns AttributeError: Unknown property sharey. Makes sense since the documentation doesn't list it as a scatter argument

Comment: [pandas scatter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) does have [optional keywords](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot)

Comment: @fernandezcuesta but I am not using pandas scatter here. I am using regular ax.scatter.

Comment: what if you specify ylim, such as `plt.ylim(min(y_test), max(y_test)+50))`? Does the y axes get redrawn?